# Powershell wildcard character pattern issue

Tags: powershell, wildcard, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am getting the error **The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid:**

Here is the example.

```
$trimItem = "What is your house and land budget?"
$title = "(Select)</p> <p>What is your house and land budget? </p> <p>Minimum :  [MinBudget][MaxBudget"

if ($trimItem -clike "*$($title)*") {
    write-host true
}
else {
    write-host false
}
```

How can I correct this?.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a [WildcardPatternException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpatternexception?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) due to a missing closing `]`, note that `[` and `]` are special [Wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2) characters. If you want to match these characters *literally* they need to be escaped, in PowerShell, the escape character is the **backtick `` ` ``**:

```bash
[WildcardPattern]::Escape('[ ]') # Returns => `[ `]
```

However, taking a step back, seems like the order of your condition is incorrect, most likely you wanted to reverse the order of the variables for your comparison:

```bash
$title -clike "*$trimItem*" # Returns => True
```